# Cocos2d js 3.9 Load Image from URL

Tags: android, ios, image, url, cocos2d-js

I'm getting an error when trying to load image from url on IOS using cocos2d js 3.9. on web platform, it loads correctly, but on android or IOS, it doesn't load, this is my code for loading

```
var avatarLink = "http://i81.photobucket.com/albums/j223/drawkbox/cocos2dx_portrait.png";
    var self = this;
    cc.loader.loadImg(avatarLink,{isCrossOrigin : true}, function(err, texture){
        var sprite = new cc.Sprite(texture);
        sprite.setPosition(SCREEN_WIDTH/2,SCREEN_HEIGHT/2);
        self.addChild(sprite);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help the followers in the future.

An alternate way to load image from URL is, textureCache.

```
cc.textureCache.addImageAsync(URL, function(texture) {

    if (texture instanceof cc.Texture2D) {
        var sprite = new cc.Sprite(texture);
        //Add this sprite anywhere you want
    }
    else {
        cc.TextureCache.getInstance().removeAllTextures();
        // Clear textureCache once it's done.
    }

}
```